# Configure autocomplete in intellij with hamcrest and mockito dsl

Tags: java, autocomplete, intellij-idea, mockito, hamcrest

I'm wondering if its possible to configure Intellij's smart insert to suggest hamcrest and mockito dsl idioms when in test classes. Really I'm looking for something like eclipse's 'static favorites', so that when I hit ctrl + space  or ctrl +shift +space the idioms are present.

In general is it possible to configure autocomplete/smart insert or the suggestions balloon for that matter. I've looked through the settings without much luck but could easily have overlooked something.

Comment: Have you looked at live templates? I believe they are what you are looking for. (I have not worked with Eclipse, so I'm not sure what `static favorites` do in Eclipse).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to tweak the Smart Insert feature, but I was able to create my own Live Templates for Mockito. As IntelliJ was a bit limited about export, I just posted a guide to create them manually.

The page is in french but the most important parts should be understandable for an english speaking reader.

http://blog.arkey.fr/2011/10/21/quelques-live-template-intellij-pour-mockito/

There might be some typo error in the page, also these Live Templates were created on a older version of IntelliJ. Let me know if you encounter issues about them.

And you should be able create your own live templates for Hamcrest. Also did you tried FEST-Assert, I found the API of this library pretty nice to use.

Cheers

Comment: These live templates are cool and I'll definitely start using them,  but they are not exactly what I'm looking for as I'd need to add one for each of the dsl methods. the static favorites inspects the class automatically adds the static methods of a class to the autocomplete. If i add the Hamcrest matcher class then all its static match methods are easily accessible. its really very useful for this sort of coding. I will keep digging. Thanks for the links though.

Comment: Hi @sgargan Nice that you found them useful. Maybe the Smart Insert feature is tweakable via plugins, although I don't know any that do these tricks.

Answer (score 0):

In terms Eclipse's favourite imports feature: when using Intellij, have you tried using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>?

When I use Mockito I just write `mock(MyService.class)` and then pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> gives me the option to statically import the method `Mockito.mock`.

Comment: what should I do to import ``Mockito.*`` on static import?